# Over 15 minutes (and counting) startup time for a demo Kubernetes cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I am following the instructions from here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstart

When running the `gcloud container clusters create [CLUSTER_NAME]` command, it's been running for well over 15 minutes. (Yesterday, a custom cluster that I was creating with much large machine images started up consistently in under 3 minutes.) Is this variation normal? Is is even normal that a Kubernetes cluster creation may take well over 15 minutes (and counting)? How can one tell if "something is going wrong"? I don't see any logs in the command line, and when I run:

`gcloud container clusters list`

all I see is the word "PROVISIONING":

`NAME               LOCATION       MASTER_VERSION  MASTER_IP      MACHINE_TYPE   NODE_VERSION   NUM_NODES  STATUS
deepsearchcluster  us-central1-a  1.10.9-gke.5    35.239.29.229  n1-standard-2  1.10.9-gke.5   1          RUNNING
deepsearchgitlab   us-central1-a  1.9.7-gke.11    35.225.135.57  n1-standard-4  1.9.7-gke.7 *  1          RUNNING
demo               us-central1-a  1.10.9-gke.5                   n1-standard-1  1.10.9-gke.5   3          PROVISIONING`

UPDATE: It finally started after > 28 minutes....this is crazy....Is this "normal" variation? Did it take a long time because the "default" cluster uses tiny (ie 1 vCPU) nodes with little RAM? Any suggestions on how I can minimize this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem *appears* to be because of creating multiple node pools all from a single command separated by "&&" operand and then running it all on Windows. (It may also occurr on Linux). Basically, because there were multiple commands and the command line is interactive, it was waiting for "user input" before moving on to the next command....Not sure if "--quiet" would help here, but will investigate.

Comment: When the cluster in Provisioning status, it is usually waiting for resources being reserved for the nodes. The nodes and the cluster aren't running yet in that status. The reason depends on specific settings you selected for the nodes, e.g. their size, image, etc. If you share more information, we can help better.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this by adding the --async so you can continue next steps while waiting its creations...

```
gcloud container clusters create test --node-locations=us-east4-a --num-nodes=1  --async
gcloud container clusters create staging --node-locations=us-east4-a --num-nodes=1  --async
gcloud container clusters create prod --node-locations=us-east4-a --num-nodes=1  --async
```